# Posting Json data to a URL and fetching same data from URL simultaneously

Tags: java, json, http

This might be a very silly question but sorry for that,
I have to post data at a given URL and then i want to fetch the same data from that URL at client side.

My confusion is that how do i know that the data that i have posted could be received at client URL at the same time?

I can write the program for posting and fetching the data individually but how can be sure that after posting data, it would be received, means when the data is posted at a given URL, where it supposed to be stored, so that it can be fetched at later time, Do the client side need to write some sort of logic that when some data hit to this URL, store it somewhere(db etc), or what really this would be?

Comment: Why do you really want to store the data on URL(Query String)? Can't you just store it in a Javascript **global variable**? Or else you could take advantage of *Session variable*. (This is much easier)

Comment: The url to which you are posting data must be giving some response. You can rely on that. You can also check for headers in response like "200 OK". After you get response you can go for fetching data

Comment: @Jude Niroshan i want to check my logic and code whether it is working fine or not, before pushing data on to client URL thats why i was thinking to send my data to some dummy URL, and check at that dummy URL that  pushing code is working fine or not

Comment: @Max My first suggestion would be better.(*I think so... *)

Comment: @Dhruv Pal exactly what u r saying that is only my confusion, The dummy url to which i am posting data will give some response, still when i did not write any logic for client side, Is it something like http code i ll get automatically ?

Comment: I am taking about some rest api's where you can post data, store it as you like and fetch data. If you want to store small data and don't need to persist it on application restart , I would not suggest it. Then go storing it in as suggested in 1, else you have to go this way

Comment: @Dhruv Pal yes i am suppose to write rest API, i will post data at a given URL,what is in my thinking, i dont know whether i am correct or not,   when i will post my data, the data must be some where to store so that when i ll fetch data from that URL, i ll get that whole content of that data,  is it like this only?  or may be the case that when i am fetching data from URL, the case of fetching data from URL might be different, without storing anywhere we can get data directly from URL what has been posted there ?

Comment: Please answer these 1)Is this your data storing one time activity 2) Do you want to persist data if app restarts 3) Are you posting same data everytime?

Comment: @DhruvPal actually i am trying to write a client by myself that can test my post data that i suppose to post at a particular URL, i need not to store any data anytime just i was asking so that i can verify the data at client side just for my verification purpose

Comment: So you just want to test your client Right. If that's it then for testing either you need to create a server exposed api(I prefer rest service and its pretty easy), the exposed url in api will act as url for you or I am not sure if there is any tool online for that.

Comment: @DhruvPal ..ok i will write a rest service with a dummyURL where i can post data from my code, so how would i test here in my rest client code whether my pushed data reached here or not after posting data from that code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82929/discussion-between-dhruv-pal-and-max).